# Globally installed node-dev causes error "command not found"

Tags: node.js, npm, node-dev

So that I don't have to keep [restarting node.js during development](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6310968/61654) I'm trying to use [node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev). Unfortunately, when I try to run node-dev from terminal I receive the error:

> $ node-dev server.js
>   -bash: node-dev: command not found

I have globally installed node-dev via the `npm install node-dev -g` command. The output from this command is:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-dev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-dev
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/growl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/growl
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/node-dev -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/node-dev/node-dev
node-dev@0.2.9 /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/node-dev
└── growl@1.6.1
```

To be sure node-dev is installed globally I've run `npm ls -g` which returns:

```
/usr/local/share/npm/lib
└─┬ node-dev@0.2.9
  └── growl@1.6.1
```

Some other posts have indicated that my globally installed npm modules should be in the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder instead of `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/`. I can't tell if this is for older versions of npm or something that actually matters.

I'm new to both Mac OS X and Node development so it wouldn't surprise me that I was overlooking something trivial. What haven't I done which is causing me to get a "command not found" error when trying to utilize node-dev? Is there some sort of $PATH environment issue I'm overlooking?

One note I don't have Growl installed but the node-dev documentation indicated it was optional.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be your issue, and [here's a walk-through](http://hadihariri.com/2012/02/26/automating-testing-with-mocha-and-webstorm/) to fixing it.  It's specifically for WebStorm & Mocha, but seems like it could be related.  I think you may need to setup an alias.

> **env: node: No such file or directory**
>
> Reason for this is that when running GUI applications under MacOSX,
>   the environment variables are not the same as those when you run a
>   from a terminal. In particular, node for instance is not on the path.
>   To overcome this issue, you can either launch WebStorm from the
>   terminal (yuck!) or solve it. Fortunately this isn’t as hard as it
>   once was. Here’s a Tip on our forum for RubyMine but it applies to all
>   IDE’s including WebStorm. In essence, its creating an
>   environment.plist file inside ~/.MacOSX which contains your full path.
>   Mine is here if you want to download it. Make sure you reboot your
>   machine after doing this step.
>
> **Setting up an alias**
>
> Everything should be working now, but instead of
>   having to type this in each time, lets set up an alias for it in
>   WebStorm. Click on Preferences (CMD+, under MacOSX) and type in
>   Command to get to the command line tools. Click on the + button to
>   create a new entry and confirm the dialog box to create a new custom
>   framework.
>
> [image]

Comment: Sorry for this post dangling. The holiday got the better of me and pulled me away from all development. Unfortunately, I think my issue has to do w/ the actual node-dev install. As indicated in my question I can't get it to run from terminal. The linked post indicates that nodemon should just work after install. I'd imagine node-dev to work the same way and in fact after trying the first part of the post received the same error when trying to run nodemon. Because of this I edited and refocused the question on my npm global install & will circle back around to sublime once terminal is working.